# Set VLC for Windows 8 as the default 3gp player

Tags: windows-8.1, vlc-media-player

How do I set VLC for windows 8 (store version) as the default 3gp video player in Windows 8.1, when right clicking on a file from Windows explorer and selecting "open with" it does not list VLC. When going to control panel I can't see 3gp as a file extension for VLC while VLC can open these. The problem here windows 8 default video app doesn't open 3gp and I have to open VLC first then open the file from there.

Please note, I am using the [Windows 8 store version of VLC (Modern UI)](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/c527ff2d-b5d0-45b6-bfc3-92fb7357ef72).

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

You can set VLC for Windows 8 as your default player for video (see how below), but only 7 file types can currently be associated with it:

[image]

I have a question out to the dev team to see if it's on the roadmap. VLC for Windows 8 is in its early stages, so I'm sure there will be updates soon.

---

### Instructions for setting default video player

Win 8 will let you choose a metro app as your default player for media apps. To access the settings, open the Charms menu (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>). Select Settings.

[image]

Choose Change PC Settings.

[image]

Choose Search & Apps.

[image]

Choose Defaults.

[image]

Click the Default Video Player icon. You can see that mine is currently set to the desktop version of VLC, because it doesn't have the uniform Metro icon.

[image]

Choose VLC for Windows 8 to use the app version of VLC as the default player for all videos.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I know this and I mentioned in my question that 3gp is not listed in control panel, sorry your answer does not help me at all.

Comment: @MeNoTalk Unfortunately, it looks like 3gp is not currently supported for the Windows 8 version of VLC. You **can** associate it with the desktop version of VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel > Default Programs > Set Default Programs. From the 'Programs' list select VLC and after that 'Choose default for this program'. In the new window tick .3gp and hit save and OK.

Comment: 3gp is not listed there, as I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Microsoft Account so **I cannot verify that this works with Metro apps** too, but it's worth a shot. This will make VLC default for all filetypes is associated with, **not just 3gp**.

[image]

Navigate to "Control Panel/Programs/Default Programs/Set Default Programs". Find the program on the left hand side list, click it, and then click "Choose defaults for this program" from the bottom displayed options.

[image]

Check the box for the desired file types, and click save. They will now be associated with the program in question.

[image]

Navigate once again to "Control Panel/Programs/Default Programs/Set Default Programs". Find the program on the left hand side list, click it, and then click "Set program as default". The program will now default for all file types it's associated with.

Comment: I have mentioned twice in my question that I was dealing with VLS for windows 8, the metro version, the new UI version, the store version, hence your answer is wrong.

Comment: @MeNoTalk I was aware of this, even mentioned that it in my post. This menu lists different programs than the set file associations screen does, and so I figured VLC "might" show up here even if it didn't in the other one.